# Examine cocos2d's nodes tree

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am already finishing my game and I am trying to fix some memory issues.

My game has 36 levels and I noticed that when I run it in an iPod, after 20-25 levels my app crashes. I start getting memory warnings and it always crashes when transitioning between scenes.

I have already used instruments to fix every memory leak but this is still happening.
My guess is that cocos is still holding references to old objects.

I would like to find a way to look through the cocos' nodes hierarchy in certain points of my game to make sure everything is ok.

Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: Is printing out the nodes enought to "look through" them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

I added some logic in the `CCDirector` to "draw" the hierarchy:

```
-(void) printChildren:(CCNode *)node andLevel:(NSInteger)level {

    NSString *tabs = @"";
    for (int i=0; i <level; i++) {
        tabs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  ", tabs];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@NODE %@. Children count: %d", tabs, node, node.children.count);
    if ( node.children.count == 0 ) {
        return;
    } else {
        for (CCNode *child in node.children) {
            [self printChildren:child andLevel:level+1];
        }
    }
}

-(void) nodeHierarchy
{

    NSLog(@"Printing nodeHierarchy! with an stack of %d scenes", [scenesStack_ count]);
    for (CCScene *scene in scenesStack_) {
        NSLog(@"Scene in stack: %@", [scene class]);
        [self printChildren:scene andLevel:0];
    }
}
```

I call `nodeHierarchy` in the `replaceScene` method.

It would be great to have a more visual tool, but this worked for me.

Comment: One simple method is to add a breakpoint or log statement to your scene's dealloc method. If this is not triggered after you changed a scene, you know that you have a memory leak (and that's a leak that probably won't register in Instruments).

Answer (score 1):

I have modified CCTextureCache to log which textures are retained and which others are released, at critical steps in my games, where i force a 'removedUnusedTextures', notably on scene transitions. Whatever you see there should give a hint of where to look in your app. Also, i tend to tag everything with a unique tag, and remember the tags in every class that adds stuff to a CCNode. In the wash (cleanup), i rundown the array of tags, and force remove them.

Comment: hmmm ... ok, you got the t-shirt. Well, also faced with similar issues, i have got myself JetBrain's AppCode. It snared ou many hidden issues in my code that slipped right through Analyse and Instruments. Best of luck with your product. AppCode is not a replacement for Xcode, but a great tool for coding-debug phases of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you cannot migrate to SDK 5.0 that has ARC.

Comment: My alloc/releases are ok, I am not seeing any leak in Instruments.

Comment: @Aman Every update of Xcode has been a walk through hell for me. Being close to publishing a few products would be an excellent reason not to update. There are no reasons to believe that ARC is all that hot either, coming from that perspective.